# Extracting n-length vector out of data frame

Tags: r

Good day,

I'm working on a fairly large data set (~300k rows within a 1k bootstrap) and am trying hard to avoid tedious loops. For each row in the data frame, I need to extract a vector from one of the columns, and determine its minimum. The vector's length would be determined by the value in another column.

A small example:

```
dat <- data.frame(temp = rnorm(10, 10, 2), 
                  start = c(1:10), 
                  end = c(3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10))
```

Taking temp to be the extraction source column, for the first row, the code would have to extract temp[1:3] and estimate its minimum. For the 9th row, temp[9:10] would be extracted and its  minimum calculated. The vector of minimum values would then be added as a new column to the data frame.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `mapply`:

```
> mapply(function (from, to) min(dat$temp[from : to]), dat$start, dat$end)
 [1]  7.977614  7.977614 10.497931  7.874876  7.874876  8.866633  8.866633
 [8]  8.866633  9.828296 10.421222
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the super-quick helping hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree with Konrad, you can use mcmapply() for a parallel version, from package "parallel"

Answer (score 0):

@Konrad answer is great but just for the fun, you can also use `apply`

```
apply(dat, 1, function(x) min(dat$temp[x[2]:x[3]]))
```

or like this

```
apply(dat, 1, function(x) min(dat$temp[x["start"]:x["end"]]))
```

Comment: No please, the first time `apply` breaks your function, you'll know not to use it with data frames.

Comment: `apply` converts its argument into a matrix, so if your df contains character or factor vars, the end result will also be character, so your function will likely fail.

Comment: Thanks I'll pay attention then.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a `tidyverse` approach to this:

```
pmap_dbl(list(start = dat$start, end = dat$end), function(x, start, end) 
     min(x$temp[start:end]), x = dat)
```